# How can I disable a DropDownlist in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i am bind the FixedBYId to bind the Dropdownlist ...to dispaly the dropdownlist not edit the data

```
MY View Code
-------------
  <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Gridview_BugTracker.Models.BugTracker_DataHelper>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>BugHistory</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

     <%: ViewBag.Title = "BugHistory"%>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       { %>      
      <%:Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>      

        <fieldset>
        <legend>BugHistory</legend>

       <div class="editor-label">
           <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.FixedByID)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeName)%>
            <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeName)%>
        </div>     


        <form action="BugHistory.aspx" method="post">  
        <p> <input type="submit" value="BugHistoryInsert" /></p> 
        </form>           
          </fieldset>   
       <% }%>            
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

This is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?
  Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: Can you try to clarify your problem a bit further?  I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: @miscusermandude... just want be dropdownlist disable..

Comment: I don't know what this means: "i am bind the FixedBYId to bind the Dropdownlist ...to dispaly the dropdownlist not edit the data"  Can you clarify?

Comment: @miscusermandude...Actualy in my application i have Dropdown so just want to disbale(disapper) when i want

Comment: I apologize - I think we are having a translation issue.  You may really need to look to revise how your post is phrased in order to get a proper response.  I can't really help any further.

Comment: @miscusermandude..sorry for not given to proper response..actualy am asking litile bit confuse so ..........

Comment: if you want to disable any html element, you can just make use of the HtmlAttributes that will be available for any html helper like Html.TextBox etc.. you can set it like 
`Html.DropDownList("items",ViewBag.Items,new {@disabled="disabled"});`